# Are any of the T0 sets still available in the game?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When I learned that you can now transmog gear like in Diablo 3, it made me instantly regret to have thrown away T0 Sets due to lack of space.

Can you still farm all of the set parts in the current version of WoW which is Draenor at the time of writing?

Comment: If you're looking for transmog stuff, Wowhead has some good guides on all of it. This news post they just put up for Warlords of Draenor is a good start: http://www.wowhead.com/news=244071/warlords-of-draenor-transmog-set-database-and-guides-live

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

However, the Darkmoon Faire does offer replica items from the t0 sets in exchange for tickets. They add no stats but can (and are intended to) be used in transmogficiation.

Comment: Now just to wait for the next Darkmoon Faire I guess

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Dungeon_Set_1) these sets no longer drop. As of patch 4.0.3, they are no longer acquirable.

Comment: In the future you should use [Wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org) instead of WoWwiki. Wowpedia is more up-to-date and also used by Blizzard (so I guess in a way endorsed?)

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers:

If you do a character boost to 90, you also get some items that combined look like a T0 Set of the respective class you are boosting. Here is my Mage after boosting him from 80 to 90:

[image: Screenshot of a T0 Set imposter]